# LSTM: Keras for Python 3.7.4

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, python-3.7

On Windows 10 I installed Keras on Python 3.7.4 using: `pip install keras`
I don't get an error message.
 However, when I then want to call Keras functions in my Spyder Script: 
`from keras.models import Sequential` it gives the following error message:

> File "C:/Users/marti/.spyder-py3/LSTM-experiment.py", line 20, in 
>       from keras.models import Sequential
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

To double check, I ran "*import keras*" on the Python console and get the following error:

> C:\Users\marti>python
>   Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > import keras
> > >       Using TensorFlow backend.
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in 
> > >           from . import utils
> > >         File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 6, in 
> > >           from . import conv_utils
> > >         File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
> > >           from .. import backend as K
> > >         File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 1, in 
> > >           from .load_backend import epsilon
> > >         File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in 
> > >           from .tensorflow_backend import *
> > >         File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
> > >           import tensorflow as tf
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I assume Keras needs Tensorflow to be fully installed. Could it be that Keras/ Tensorflow is still not running with Python 3.7.4? If not, is there any other machine learning package I should use to implement time series LSTM? Many thanks for any pointers, Martin :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not downgrade your python version? It seems that is not yet straightforward to install TensorFlow with `Python 3.7.x`.

As for alternative packages, you can maybe use this one that is for Matlab  that can be found [here](http://mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/%E2%80%A6) or you can try the `Pytorch` version of `LSTM` that can be found in [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html).

Comment: still not working, Chris Does anyone know if Tensorflow/ Keras will run on Python 3.7.4 anytime soon?

Comment: LSTM worked fine with Python 3.7.4 and Pytorch 1.3.1. Thanks! I used Jessica Yung's excellent blog to get started. Check out https://www.jessicayung.com/lstms-for-time-series-in-pytorch/